# display:none doesn't hide the div content

Tags: html, css

it's supposed to be obvious, but in all major browsers, the div content is not hidden:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>

<style>
    #confContent{
    border:solid 1px #FF0000;
    width:700px;
        height:600px;
    background-color:#00CC00;
    left:50%;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
                                                }

</style>

</head>

<body>

        <div id="confContent">
        <p style="color:#0000FF">Some content goes here</p>
        </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Actually, all the prperties doesn't seems to work, the `div` is not shifted to 30% left, doesn't have a background color, is not hidden and doesn't have a border. Please help. Thanx in advance.

Comment: It is hidden in Chrome. Also please use width:700px instead of width:700

Comment: There must be something wrong elsewhere in your page; your code (as you've entered it here) works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/A9F3L/

Comment: updated my answer - you are missing `<html>` tag in your new code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue is solved, for anyone who struggle with this, DO NOT use `<!-- -->` for your comments  inside your css block:

```
<style>

<!-- DO NOT use this format for comments -->

/* Only this format is valid */

</style>
```

That was preventing FireFox from reading my css code and was throwing me such errors:

```
The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must to be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.
```

and

```
Unexpected end of file while searching for closing } of invalid rule set.
```

Answer (score 4):

your CSS needs to be in a style tag (if not in an external stylesheet)

```
<style>
#confContent{

    border:solid 1px #FF0000;
    width:700px;
    height:600px;
    background-color:#00CC00;
    left:30%;
    display:none;
}   
</style>
```

And should be placed in the `head` of your page

Looking at your new code, you are missing the HTML tag at the beginning of your document (should be after the `<!DOCTYPE html>`)

However, i don't think this is the problem either - i think maybe there is some more CSS we are not seeing which is overwritting the div's properties you've given us.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your code by :

```
<!--Confirmation div-->
<div id="confContent">
   <p style="color:#0000FF">Some content</p>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
#confContent{
    border:solid 1px #FF0000;
    width:700px;
    height:600px;
    background-color:#00CC00;
    left:30%;
    display:none;
}     
</style>
```

Use Danny Hearnah suggestion regarding HEAD tag

Comment: Style tags can't occur anywhere except the document head.  I'm assuming you already know that and are just using the tags to illustrate, but I suspect the OP may need to be told that.

Comment: Thanks for the precision @GordonM. Yes I already knew that, but it's easier for explaination, to put the style tag directly below the HTML code, regarding malloc problem

Comment: That's obvious, sure i put all in a `style` tag between the `head` tags, sorry for not mentioning that in my post :)

Comment: I edited my post, this time i moved to a blank file to test on it. Same problem, the css code is not interpreted.

Comment: Your code seems correct : http://jsfiddle.net/C9WvK/
Can you please post your development URL so we can check directly ?

Comment: Try adding type="text/css" to your style tag... the code works, honest! http://jsfiddle.net/hMFQQ/

Comment: Stupid question: you haven't managed to disable CSS in your browser, have you?

Comment: What do you mean? can you clarify?

Comment: I am testing on chrome, IE9, FireFox. css code doesn't work on all.

Comment: What @MassivePenguin is telling you, is that on FF (for example), you can disable CSS interpretation by the browser. Can you please provide your development URL so we can check ?

Comment: Yep, that's right Laurent. And Malloc - if you have four or five people all telling you the code is fine, chances are it's fine. There's something else at play here ;)

Answer (score 1):

You missed `px` of the `width` property. Other than that it's working. Check this [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ad3sD/)

And if this is still not working then you need to check your CSS File Path

Comment: Hi, i edited my post, everything seems obvious, i moved my code to new file to see if it has a problem dealing with my original post. However, the same problem occur, the css code doesn't appear to work.